# I want to set HTML bookmarks within android TextView, so I can use it to allow readers to jump to specific parts of the page

Tags: android, textview, autolink

Here is what I have in my xml file:

```
android:autoLink="all|web|phone|map|email"
```

The other links to web pages, phone numbers, and email addresses work fine. When it comes to bookmarks, it is shown like a plain text and it has no functionality.
I am new in android. Can anyone please give me any instruction on this?

Comment: why don't you use a WebView?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make `TextView` do stuff exactly as in `html` pages. You'll probably be able to achieve that by  writing a custom logic in `onClick` for the `TextView`.

I think you should use a `WebView`.  With `WebView` your `href`s will work in the html.

Comment: So I should find every href with # and do a search within the textView to find  tag with that id. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Updated my answer with a possibility

Comment: Thanks. I will try this way